# codeigniter, get the maximum value in mysql table column

Tags: codeigniter, select, max

i'm using codeigniter 2.
i've a mysql table column storing the time taken for each student.
eg. 1.2327, 0.6547, 1.9876

i want to get the max. value that column.

This is my code:

```
$this->db->select_max('time_taken', 'time');
$result = $this->db->get('students');  
echo $result->row()->time;
```

when i echo the result, it give me a value of 2(correct value should be 1.9876).
What is the correct way to get this value i need, thanks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->db->select_max('time_taken AS time');
$result = $this->db->get('students')->row();  
echo $result->time;
```

Edit: Make sure your database table field (i.e time_taken) is decimal, NOT integer.

Comment: i still get the same value 2

Comment: What data type is the database field?

Comment: haha, it was integer, i'll change it and see what's happen, thanks

Comment: try: $this->db->select('MAX(time_taken) AS time',false);

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select_max('time_taken');
$this->db->from('students');
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```