# Get maximum value of row in mysql ,using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Get maximum value of row in mysql using codeigniter.
i have following mysql data [image]

I need to get the details based on `total_payment` of each student.
like this[image]

i tried code below

```
 $student_id_dis = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT(student_id) FROM student_fees')->result_array();
 $fee_cat_id_dis = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT(fee_category_id) FROM student_fees')->result_array();
 $this->db->select(['student_fees.*', 'fee_categories.fee_category_name as fee_name', 'fee_categories.amount as fee_amount']);

 $this->db->join('student', 'student_fees.student_id = student.student_id');
 $this->db->join('fee_categories', 'student_fees.fee_category_id = fee_categories.fee_categories_id');

 $where = '';

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($student_id_dis); $i++) {
    if (isset($fee_cat_id_dis[$i]['fee_category_id'])) {
        $where .='total_paid = (SELECT max(stdp.total_paid)
                                   FROM student_fees stdp
                                   WHERE stdp.fee_category_id = ' . $fee_cat_id_dis[$i]['fee_category_id'] . ')';
     }

     $this->db->where($where);

     $this->db->get('student_fees')->result_array();
      }
```

Comment: looking at your desire result you are searching for minimum  **balance**

Comment: am I right ?...

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538359/codeigniter-get-the-maximum-value-in-mysql-table-column

Comment: @knowledge.... get last payment where each student and each fee_category

Comment: So you can say this if student pay fee it has lowest balance right ?

Comment: In your code joins are outside of the loop so they will run only for the first iteration.

Comment: Which max value you want, for ex: fee_amount, total_paid, amount??

Comment: @knowledge.... No  `total_paid` it has highest value.

Comment: @AmarjytChahal `total_paid` is maximum value

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from student_fees where student_fees_id in 
(select student_fees_id from 
  where total_paid =max(total_paid) group by fee_category_id)
```